# how can I find all tickets that changed/moved projects?

Tags: jira, jql

The query I tried is `Project CHANGED FROM "Customer triage"`, but jira says it's not supported.

Is there a way to query the tickets that were created in project A, but were moved?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, this is not possible to do out of box with JIRA; "Project" just doesn't support any historic search functionality:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver073/advanced-searching-fields-reference-861257219.html#Advancedsearchingfieldsreference-ProjectProject

However, with some Googling, it appears you may be able to accomplish this with ScriptRunner:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/View-issues-that-have-been-moved-from-one-project-to-another/qaq-p/790346